# Using value from date picker in SSRS

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, reporting-services

I have an SSRS report that has two nullable date picker parameters - start and end date.

In my query I want to select values between these dates or if either date (or both) is null.

I've tried:

```
WHERE ... AND (StartDateTime >= @FromDateTime OR his.StartDateTime is null) AND (EndDateTime <= @ToDateTime OR EndDateTime is null)
```

and variations on this but I can't get it to work.  I'm thinking of writing a stored proc to do this with temp tables but wanted to see if there's a simple way to do this in my where clause.

Comment: What's mean  `I can't get it to work` could you provide some sample data and expected result?

Comment: This looks like it would work. Is it the date in the **parameter** that can be NULL (@FromDateTime) or the date in the **data** (his.StartDateTime)? You're checking the **data** and not the parameter. `...OR @FromDateTime IS NULL...`

Answer (score 0):

There are a few possible scenarios here.

**You want the parameter to be optional**

This is usually called a kitchen sink query.

```
WHERE <some conditions>
    AND (StartDateTime >= @FromDateTime OR @FromDateTimeis null) 
    AND (EndDateTime <= @ToDateTime OR @ToDateTime is null)
```

You'll want to read a couple of blogs on this.

- [Aaron Bertrand Kitchen Sink](https://blogs.sentryone.com/aaronbertrand/backtobasics-updated-kitchen-sink-example/)
- [Erland Sommarskog Dynamic Search Conditions](http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search.html)

**Your StartDateTime & EndDateTime is NULLABLE**

In this case, you want to compare the `NULL` parameter to the `NULL` date

```
WHERE <some conditions>
    AND (StartDateTime >= @FromDateTime OR (@FromDateTime is null and StartDateTime is null)) 
    AND (EndDateTime <= @ToDateTime OR (@ToDateTime is null and EndDateTime is null))
```

**You want the optinal parameter logic to apply to the data, not the parameter**

This is basically what you already have, which is why I don't expect it is what you want.

```
WHERE <some conditions>
    AND (StartDateTime >= @FromDateTime OR StartDateTime is null) 
    AND (EndDateTime <= @ToDateTime OR EndDateTime is null)
```